# URL Redirection not working with Requests, Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

```
import requests

def extractlink():
    with open('extractlink.txt', 'r') as g:
        print("opened extractlink.txt for reading")
        contents = g.read()
        headers = {'userAgent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36'}
        r = requests.get(contents, headers=headers)
        print(("Links to " + r.url))
        time.sleep (2)
```

Currently, r.url is just linking to the url found in 'extractlink.txt'

I'm looking to fix this script to find the final redirected url and print the result. It appears the issue lies somewhere in the request for the URL, despite trying many alternatives and troubleshooting steps, my issue doesn't seem to be solved like the rest.

When debugging, `r.history` reads as `[]` and `r.status_code` reads as `403` even though the link redirects as a 302 in browser.
Any ideas?

(extractlink.txt is just a one line file with a link to a redirect/link shortener)

Comment: Your code worked fine when I tried it, so it's unclear what issue there is... how are you putting the `url` in your `extractlink.txt` file? (it should be like `https://example.com`)

Comment: avoid asking the same question in several post

Comment: Code returns a 403 for me @l'L'l link is a `http://xxxx` The website works fine on wheregoes and browser.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to tell without your data, but you may have a line ending in your text file that is changing the URL. You might change `read()` to:

```
contents = g.readline().strip()
```

You might also try executing the request using a `Session` object:

```
with requests.Session() as session:
    r = session.get(contents, headers=headers)
```

Comment: Still returns a 403, `contents` returns the proper url, the issue lies elsewhere.

Comment: I've also tried executing the request using `session`, I've done plenty of research before making my post but haven't found a solution.