# URL redirect returning a 403 rather than 302

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

```
import requests

def extractlink():
    with open('extractlink.txt', 'r') as g:
        print("opened extractlink.txt for reading")
        contents = g.read()
        headers = {'userAgent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36'}
        r = requests.get(contents, headers=headers)
        print(("Links to " + r.url))
        time.sleep (2)
```

Currently, r.url is just linking to the url found in 'extractlink.txt'

I'm looking to fix this script to find the final redirected url and print the result. It appears the issue lies somewhere in the request for the URL, despite trying many alternatives and troubleshooting steps, my issue doesn't seem to be solved like the rest.

When debugging, `r.history` reads as `[]` and `r.status_code` reads as `403` even though the link redirects as a 302 in browser.
Any ideas?

(extractlink.txt is just a one line file with a link to `http://butterup.teechip.icu/`, enter with your own caution, spam website)

Once again, this is not a duplicate, I'd appreciate if you stop marking it as such. The information and code has changed, as well as the error/goals.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [URL Redirection not working with Requests, Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53825743/url-redirection-not-working-with-requests-python)

Comment: @l'L'l oh man, this is a duplicate of a duplicate.

Comment: You  did ask the almost exact same question which got closed as dupe ... of the question you asked before that with less detail but same question anyway ...

Comment: Yeah, it was *extremely* similar. Almost scarily similar, question format and content.

Comment: Well, I guess, we could leave this one opened as others are closed. Hope the answer helps and we can resolve the situation here.

Comment: @alecxe Apparently not, It seems ya'll are out to get me here. I've posted this nearly 3 times, with more information added each time, with different questions. This is not a duplicate, the questions have evolved as well as the information added, I've still not found a solution.

Comment: A 403 typically means permission denied. Does this site you are requesting require credentials to view?

Comment: No @JaredMackey, the site is easily accessed through a browser and resolved in a site like `wheregoes.com`

Comment: @l'L'l This isn't a duplicate.... Read the damn title for Christ's sake. Oddly enough, you've contributed nothing to the discussion and are actively preventing me from finding a solution, despite trying to provide everything one could ask for.

Comment: @Dansey I’m not preventing anything; you’ve basically posted the same question three times. Why not edit the original and maybe this type of thing wouldn’t happen.

Comment: The original was edited, It's also been downvoted and it's old enough where people won't be visiting the question. I see no point in commenting on a dead question. @l'L'l You say it's the same question when it's clearly not, see the first post before any revisions. You're also absolutely preventing an answer. By removing my post, I am almost certainly never going to get a response.

Comment: @Dansey I'm not removing any posts, so I'm not sure how you are coming to that conclusion. Your posts all looked more or less the same with a few changes in the wording, although ultimately aren't you trying to resolve the same issue in all of them? Maybe stop pointing the finger at others when you should be looking toward why you might not have gotten this resolved yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite many attempts at troubleshooting, It appears the answer lies in the host used for the script returning a 403 on sites that aren't whitelisted.

Answer (score 1):

You've just misnamed the `User-Agent` header:

```
headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36'}
r = requests.get(contents, headers=headers)
```